# php function that outputs array, how do I print specific object?

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
wp_gdsr_blog_rating()
```

And when I print_r it it outputs this:

```
stdClass Object ( [count] => 20 [rating] => 3.7 [bayes_rating] => 3.7 [max_rating] => 5 [percentage] => 74 [voters] => 71 [votes] => 260.0 )
```

How do I grab and print only [voters] value?

Comment: `wp_gdsr_blog_rating()->voters`?

Comment: @arxanas I like your way of writing clean syntax. I used that. can we make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$o = wp_gdsr_blog_rating();
echo $o->voters;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sandro Dzneladze,  the function

```
wp_gdsr_blog_rating()
```

returning a standard class object say like

```
<?php

class Obj {
    public $count = 20;
    public $rating = 3.7;
    public $voters = 71;
    public $votes = 260.0;
}
$var = new Obj();

print_r($var);
echo '<br/>';
echo $var->votes;
?>
```

So it is same as you create a object of class and return it. So you can access as same as accessing the class object.